# How to make cursor visible with inputype set to null?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am creating a simple calculator app which has a `Edittext` and some buttons to take input from user.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    style="@style/editTextStyle"
    android:text="0"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Following is the `java` code.

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

I set the input type to null so that when the user taps on the `edittext`, the default system keyboard stays hidden. But this also makes the cursor invisible. When I insert some text into the `Edittext` and taps on it, the cursor position changes but the cursor is not visible.

Is there any way to make the cursor visible with input type set to null??

**Update:**

I tried using the following code.

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

This solution works for android versions till Nougat. When I tap on Edittext, the system keyboard stays hidden and cursor is visible. But in Oreo, this solution does not work. When I tap on Editext, the system keyboard pops up.

is there any way to keep system keyboard hidden while cursor is visible??

Comment: not need to set null, whenever edit field will focus cursor will show.

Comment: change this editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `Activity`:
              `editText.setFocusable(true);`
   
 `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT‌​_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to InputType.TYPE_NULL
In onCreate() of the activity where you have the edittext box:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mAmountText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);

// This will disable the Soft Keyboard from appearing by default
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

// Provide focus to the Amount box (since it is the top edittext box inside RelativeLayout)
mAmountText.requestFocus();

}
```

In your layout file (call it note_edit.xml):

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>

<RelativeLayout
android:id=”@+id/main_layout”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
android:background=”#ffffffff”
android:descendantFocusability=”beforeDescendants”
android:focusableInTouchMode=”true”
>

<EditText
android:id=”@+id/amount”
android:textColor=”#ff0066ff”
android:numeric=”decimal”
android:gravity=”left”
android:hint=”$0.00″
android:textSize=”48sp”
android:layout_height=”72dp”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:windowSoftInputMode=”stateHidden”
>
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```